# my property file seems not to be implemented by build.xml

Tags: ant

I have a problem with properties.
here is content of my build.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<project name="default" default="package">
<target name="init">
<mkdir dir="build/classes" />
<mkdir dir="dist" />
</target>
<property file="${basedir}/localproperties"/>
<property name="javac.debug" value="off"/>
<target name="compile" depends="init" description="Compiles JAVA files">
<echo message="Debug: ${javac.debug}"/>
<javac srcdir="src" 
    destdir="build/classes"
    classpathref="compile.classpath"
    debug="${javac.debug}"/>
</target>
<path id="compile.classpath">
<fileset dir="lib" includes="*.jar"/>
</path>
</project>
```

and here is content of my localproperties file:

```
javac.debug = on
```

please note that I have saved localproperties as .xml file and put it into the same directory as build.xml

the problem is that it does not work as the output I get is:
Debug: off

clearly it should be:
Debug: on

please advise.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
<property file="${basedir}/localproperties.xml"/>
```

There is no extension assumed by the `property` task. As long as the content follows the key-value convention, it can be any file extension. But it would be confusing to save as `.xml`. Just save it as `localproperties.properties`, or simply `local.properties`.